# Array value in a set of value ranges isn't displaying

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple program to display a discount depending on how many items a customer purchases.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SIZE = 4;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int itemsbought = 0;
            double discountItem = 0;
            int[] items = new int[SIZE] { 0, 10, 26, 61 };
            double[] discount = new double[SIZE] { 0.0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15 };

            InputItems(ref itemsbought);
            getDiscount(items, discount, ref itemsbought, ref discountItem);

            Console.WriteLine("Your discount is {0}", discountItem);

        }

        private static void getDiscount(int[] items, double[] discount, ref int itemsbought, ref double discountItem)
        {
            int idx = 0;
            for (idx = 1; idx >= items.Length; idx++)
            {
                while (itemsbought >= items[idx])
                {
                    discountItem = discount[idx];
                    idx++;
                }
            }
        }
        private static void InputItems(ref int itemsbought)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of items you bought");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out itemsbought))
                Console.WriteLine("Error, whole numbers only");
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow I know the logic of this is really bad but I am not sure.  The topic one being of course that the discount that aligns to the input is displaying.  It's just displaying "The discount is 0" no matter what value is inputed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is all wrong. First, it isn't executing because your condition is `idx >= items.Length;`. It should be the opposite: `idx < items.Length;`. Second, I'm not sure why you are setting `idx` to `1` in the initializer...

The inner while loop also probably doesn't do what you want it to, but I'm not even sure what it is that you want it to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the loop condition checking part, it is using a fault logic `idx >= items.Length;` which should have been `idx < items.Length;`.

Array in c# have zero based index, so, it must start with `idx = 0`.

```
for (idx = 0; idx < items.Length; idx++)
{
    while (itemsbought >= items[idx])
    {
        discountItem = discount[idx];
        idx++;
    }
}
```